# Admob test Ads not showing in real device ?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

I am having a problem because my ads are not showing in my real device but show up in an emulator, I got an error using logcat and this is what I get :

[image]

I don't know What to do to solve the problem because I feel like I did everything right.

Some of you may ask for code that may help, well here is my AdManager script, which may seem long but it is easy ..

```
public static AdManager Instance
{
    get;
    set;
}
public bool InterstitialLoaded = false;
public bool InterstitialClosed = false;

public string BannerAdId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
public string InterstitialAdId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
AdRequest request;
private BannerView bannerView;

public void requestAds()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("NoPersonalized") == 1)
    {
        request = new AdRequest.Builder().AddExtra("npa", "1").Build();
        Debug.Log("NoPersonalized ads EU");

    }
    else
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FirstTime") == 1)
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Localized") == 1)
            {
                //request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
                request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
                Debug.Log("Personalized ads EU");
            }
        }
        else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("BBb") == 1)
        {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Localized") == 0)
            {
                request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
                Debug.Log("personalized No EU");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("First time need select ");
                request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            }
        }


        else if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("NotEU") == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log("Personalized Not EU ");
            request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        }
    }



}
private void Awake()
{
    if (Instance == null)
        Instance = this;
    else
        Destroy(gameObject);
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(InterstitialAdId);

    Showbanner();
    requestAds();

    interstitialAd.LoadAd(request);
}

public void RequestBanner()
{
    bannerView = new BannerView(BannerAdId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    requestAds();
    bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    bannerView.Show();

}
public void Showbanner()
{

        RequestBanner();
}
public void HideBanner()
{
    bannerView.Destroy();
    bannerView.Hide();
    bannerView.Destroy();
}

public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    requestAds();
    interstitialAd.LoadAd(request);
    if (interstitialAd.IsLoaded())
    {

        InterstitialLoaded = true;
        interstitialAd.Show();
    }
    else
    {

    }

    interstitialAd.OnAdClosed += InterstitialAd_onAdClosed;
}

private void InterstitialAd_onAdClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    InterstitialLoaded = false;
    InterstitialClosed = true;
}

}
```

And I get two errors actually the first one is when I call my banner which means I have a problem in that method :

```
 private void Awake()
{
    if (Instance == null)
        Instance = this;
    else
        Destroy(gameObject);
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(InterstitialAdId);

    Showbanner(); // <------- Here
    requestAds();

    interstitialAd.LoadAd(request);
}
```

I am having this problem for days now, I wish anyone can help.

Any help would be much appreciated.